# Running tasks in background in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I have a condition where I have to start iperf server as daemon on specified port and if iperf server is running, I have to send response to client. I tried

```
shell_exec('iperf -s -p {port} -D');
```

but it doesn't return control / infinite loop starts.
The server will start but the code below the `shell_exec` will never be executed.
Anyone has a solution or suggestion how I should approach this to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `iperf -s -p {port} -D` happens to have stderr output, try doing this:

```
$outfile = "/tmp/erroutperf.out";
$port = 8080;
shell_exec("iperf -s -p $port -D > $outfile 2>&1");
```

basically the additional command `> /tmp/erroutperf.out 2>&1`, tells bash to save
both stderr output and stdout of a program (iperf) to a file  /tmp/erroutperf.out

getting the output of the command is:

```
file_get_contents($outfile);
```